# Expanding an arbitrary Lucene Query

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene 3.6.1. I receive a query from a user. This query may contain `+` or `-` operators, and may also contain phrases. In certain circumstances, I would like to expand the query by adding some extra terms that I compute. These terms are optional. However, any required include/exclude constraints specified by the user must be respected.

My initial strategy was to create a `BooleanQuery`, add a clause to it that contains the parsed user query, and then add further clauses that contain my expansion terms. The expansion terms would all be added as `Occur.SHOULD`. My question is how to constrain the user's query. I can imagine three possibilities:

1. The user's query contains no operators, which means I can include it as an `Occur.SHOULD` clause.
2. The user's query contains a `+` operator, so I need to include it as an `Occur.MUST` clause.
3. The user's query contains a `-` operator, but also other terms: Do I still include it as an `Occur.MUST` clause?

The question implicit in these three choices is how do I tell which condition is appropriate? I suppose I can rewrite the query and test for `BooleanQuery` instances, but that seems brittle.

I suppose can also try to tactic of creating a single string from the user's input and from my expansion terms, like this:

```
(fld1:userterm1 userterm2 -fld2:userterm3 +userterm4)^10 (fld1:expterm1)^8 (fld2:expterm2)^7 ...
```

Is this the best way to go? Or is there some elegant programmatic solution?

Comment: Not sure what you want.  Do you just want to figure out how to detect whether a user query contains required/prohibited terms?  Or what?

Comment: Yes, I want to detect that so that I can know whether to make the user's part of the query `MUST` or `SHOULD`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Not sure how useful this answer will be, but can't seem to come up with a hard and fast answer here, so I'll list a couple possibilities that come to mind:

First, a problem:

Modifying the query to look like:

```
(userquery) (other) (stuff)
```

I makes some sense to add the + with he rules you've shown, but a '-' prohibited term will be hard to respect correctly, since `(query -prohibition) (other)` will allow matches on other with prohibition present as well, and `+(query -prohibition) (other)` will require 'query' be matched.

The only way I see to really do that part right is to propagate the prohibited term into your automatically added terms as well, or extract it out to a parent query layer, more like `(query -prohibition)` --> `(query) (other) -(prohibition)`.

And with user entered queries of arbitrary complexity, that may not be a great strategy.

---

If you want to tackle it by modifying the query string, then you should probably just add any terms to the end of the query.  Nothing more to it.

I don't believe

```
(fld1:userterm1 userterm2 -fld2:userterm3 +userterm4)^10 (fld1:expterm1)^8 (fld2:expterm2)^7 ...
```

Is satisfactory, because userterm4 is only required within it's subquery, but a match Only on expterm1 is still acceptable.  However, a query like:

```
fld1:userterm1 userterm2 -fld2:userterm3 +userterm4 (fld1:expterm1)^.8 (fld2:expterm2)^.7 ...
```

Should, I think, satisfy your needs, and prevents you from having to worry about the internals of your queryparser.  **I think this is the best approach.**

---

I can also see logic in a query structured like

```
+(parsed userquery) (other stuff)
```

Effectively, always requiring a match on the user query.  Lucene implicitly does this, in a sense, as it won't return a result that matches no term, even if no required fields are present in the query.  This would then be using your added terms to impact scoring, rather than return a larger set of documents.  This doesn't quite address what your asking, but might be worth considering.

---

If, despite the aforementioned problems of applying them, you still want to detect '+' and '-' operators, I think it can be reasonably assumed that a StandardQueryParser will return a BooleanQuery at base level for any query that you need to check for these operands on.  You might have to worry about, for instance, DisjunctionMaxQueries, as well as what will happen when you have a simple query with an operator, like:

```
+myterm
```

I don't know if QueryParser would simply return a TermQuery, losing the plus (since it would be redundant without another term present).  Concerns like that make me hesitant to address it in this way.

Similarly, attempting to detect these values from the query string must make assumptions about how things are parsed, and could become complicated.

To sumamrize, I think the best options are to, either: add terms to the end of the raw query string before doing any parsing, or treat the user query as atomic, and define the appropriate booleanclause independant of it's contents when adding to a boolean clause wrapping it with whatever other queries you need to include.